# Bash Storing Variables like within for loops

Tags: bash

Given the for loop situation,
Loop1, an integer will be stored in a variable called var1.
Loop2, another integer will replace the value in var1.
Above is not what i would like.
I would like to store the second integer into a new variable called var2.
This loop will cycle for 30 loops and if i can have var1 to var30 all having different variables, that would be very awesome. thanks

My codes

```
b=1
for i in `ls RQ=RECORD\&rank=*.html | sort -V`
do


    tallyimpact=$(sed -n 's/.*has an Impact Factor of <strong>\(.*\)<\/strong>.*/\1/ip;T;q' $i) 
    var$b=$tallyimpact
    let "b++"
    blah blah blah
    blah blah blah
done
```

What i get is

```
boxplot2.sh: line 22: var1=162.500: command not found
boxplot2.sh: line 22: var2=54.420: command not found
boxplot2.sh: line 22: var3=45.661: command not found
boxplot2.sh: line 22: var4=42.860: command not found
boxplot2.sh: line 22: var5=42.351: command not found
boxplot2.sh: line 22: var6=41.392: command not found
```

Comment: Open the bash manpage, search for "Arrays".

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for i in $(seq 30); do
  let var$i=$i*$i
done
```

The result would be:

```
var1=1
var2=4
var3=9
...
```

Comment: +1 for giving the OP what (s)he asked for . . . though this probably isn't what (s)he really needs. An array would be far more appropriate.

Comment: `let` is only appropriate if you need to do arithmetic; otherwise, you need `declare`.

Comment: let will actually help me to increment the $i (i call it $b so i will use that from now on.)
Logically i think my command is right as everytime the loop flows, it should save a unique integer into the var$b but for some reason it just do not accept my command.

Answer (score 0):

The bash **indexed array** is specifically suited for what you describe. In the outer loop the value of `var1` can be set to anything you like. In the inner loop, all values, regardless of type, can be stored in an array and available for use when set. This allows the value of `var1` to be preserved across the entire outer loop. A quick example (output trimmed for brevity):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array

for ((i = 1; i < 3; i++)); do

    var1=$i                             ## set var1 to some value

    for ((j = 0; j < 30; j++)); do
        array+=( $((i * j)) )           ## fill the array '+=' adds each
    done                                ## value to the next array element

    printf "\n var1 : %d\n" "$var1"     ## output all values
    for ((j = 0; j < ${#array[@]}; j++)); do
        printf "    array[%2d] : %d\n" "$j" "${array[j]}"
    done

    unset array                         ## unset/reset array

done
```

**Output**

```
$ bash array_var1.sh

 var1 : 1
    array[ 0] : 0
    array[ 1] : 1
    array[ 2] : 2
    array[ 3] : 3
    array[ 4] : 4
    array[ 5] : 5
    array[ 6] : 6
    array[ 7] : 7
    array[ 8] : 8
    array[ 9] : 9
    array[10] : 10
    <snip>

 var1 : 2
    array[ 0] : 0
    array[ 1] : 2
    array[ 2] : 4
    array[ 3] : 6
    array[ 4] : 8
    array[ 5] : 10
    array[ 6] : 12
    array[ 7] : 14
    array[ 8] : 16
    array[ 9] : 18
    array[10] : 20
    <snip>
```

**Note:** the array is `unset` at the end of each outer loop to prevent it from retaining the values set within the loop.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this will help as what I'm really looking for is some numbers in an ever changing variable to be added into var1 automatically,  this is considered as the first loop. The second loop, again the number in that ever changing variable will change thus it will be automatically stored in var2. My next task is to compare the value in var1 with another var1 of another script.  Perhaps if I can store the value automatically into arrays, that would help alot too.

Comment: Yes, you are thinking along the right line. Generally in the outer loop, set `var1=something` then check `if ((i > 0)); then` compare `((var1 == oldvar1))` (if numeric) or `if [ "$var1" = "$oldvar1" ]` otherwise, then at the end of the loop, before the next iteration set `oldvar1="$var1"`. That way you can test the value of `var1` against its previous value each iteration. (initialize `oldvar1` before the loop) If you need to compare **between** scripts, you will need to make the value persistent between scripts by writing the value to a temp file. (see: `man mktemp`).